# Node color in the graph view when multiple labels apply

Tags: neo4j

Have some nodes with multiple labels. Labels are assigned colors for the graph output of a Match Result.

Is there a way to force a node to show a specific label color?  Am able to select the property to show on the node. The correct (more specific label) would make the graph display much more readable.

thanks,
Dave
using Neo4j CE 3.0.6 on Win10

Answer (score 1):

Probably best achieved using an external style sheet (GRASS) .

1. To create this click on the 'star' in the left-hand pane of the Neo4J browser.
2. At the bottom there is a button labeled 'Graph Style Sheet' which you can click on and then download to edit.

Once finished drop the CSS file onto the grey bar at the bottom of the Graph Style Sheet dialog at 2).

In terms of controlling the appearance when multiple labels apply this is determined by the order in which the styles are defined.

See

- [Neo4j 2.0.1 graphstyle.grass for multiple labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054684/neo4j-2-0-1-graphstyle-grass-for-multiple-labels)
- GitHub: [Better grass (graph styling) engine](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/4092)

Answer (score 0):

When the graph is displayed :

[image]

In this graph, there are 4 `User` nodes, two of them having the `Organization` label (domain is Github).

You can click on the specific label, for example `Organization` on the top, next to `*(4)` , once clicked, colors will appear on the bottom of the frame, click one of them to apply this color to the chosen label :

[image]

Comment: the one node has two labels. I followed the instructions and left-click the green label. Nothing happens.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't always work. I'm also dealing with the issue of the color of generic labels overriding colors of more specific labels. Reselecting a color for the more specific label doesn't change this behaviour for me.